# how to set up subscription service for python app

Tags: python, tkinter, authorization, payment-gateway, braintree

My head is spinning, I simply want a way where a user can subscribe to my desktop application.
My basic needs:

1. the user signs up and joins the subscription
2. once the user has joined the paid subscription they are allowed access to the python tkinter app
3. if the user leaves the subscription then they are not allowed access anymore

I've gone from license keys to sandbox Braintree but I still have no clue what to do, does anyone know how to integrate [sandbox Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3) with python tkinter or is there another way?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Why dont you set a timestamp on the first day it was used and place method on it that it needs an update or something in a year?

Comment: that wont help its a cancel any time subscription, or join anytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a web-server that will contain information about "paid" subscription.
This subscription should have key or signature that also stored on desktop.

And then when tkinter-app starting - send a request to that web-server to check if that key is "paid".
If yes - continue with app loading, else - open checkout page.

Comment: yessss something like that, do you know if there are any tutorials?

Comment: @coderoftheday first thing I found searching by "Flask + Stripe + Subscription". After that just add some API endpoint: https://medium.com/@reedrehg/a-flask-stripe-saas-template-cab289c11316 Hope that this will help.

Comment: @coderoftheday or here is even ready project for Braintree, but it is more advanced: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_flask_example

Comment: does flask work with tkinter desktop application? It’s not a web application

Comment: @coderoftheday as I mentioned, you need to have some web-server (e.g. based on Flask) that will contain all information about subscription, payments, "licence key" and etc. Then desktop-tkinter-app will ask (send http request to) it to do auth, so it can continue.